# How to refresh event dates in calendar (datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Actually I have two problems

1- I tried to highlight some dates in the calendar but, the style doesn't work after page load unless I click on the calendar then it will work

2- When I save some text I want to refresh the calendar to highlight this new event date, if I just recall the function nothing happen, maybe because I have already initialized the datapicker

for first problem I tried to add these commands after I initialized the datepicker
- `$('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();`
- `$("#datepicker").trigger("click");`
- `$('#datepicker').datepicker("refresh");`

This the code of getting Event Dates

```
 function EventDates() {

       var apiURL = '@Url.Content("~")api/GeDate';
        var eventDates = {};

        $.ajax({
            url: apiURL,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    //alert(item.Date1)
                    eventDates[new Date(item.Date1)] = new Date(item.Date1);
                });        
            }
        })
        // datepicker
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                jQuery('#calendar_date').val(dateText);
                CheckDate();
            },
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var highlight = eventDates[date];           
                if (highlight) {
                    return [true, "event", 'There is a text'];
                } else {
                    return [true, '', ''];
               }

            }
        });

        //   $('#datepicker').datepicker("refresh");

    }
```

```
function Save()
{

var params = [];
// globalDeptID
params.push({ name: "Date", value: $('#calendar_date').val()});
params.push({ name: "Message_E", value:$('#EN').val() });
params.push({ name: "CreatedBy", value: '@ViewBag.ID' });
params.push({ name: "ModifiedBy", value: '@ViewBag.ID'});
var apiURL = '@Url.Content("~")api/InsertAndUpdate';
$.ajax({
url: apiURL,
data: params,
type: "POST",
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

swal("Success", "The message has been saved successfully.", "success"); EventDates(); 
$("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");

},
error: function (err) {
//alert("An error occured. Could not submit your request.");
swal({
text: "An error occured.",
icon: "error"
});
}
})
}
```

as You see in save function I recall the function of eventDates after saving the data

```
EventDates(); 
$("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions for two problems

I put datepicker into ajax call, for second problem I destroyed the datepicker then I reinitialized it

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy"); 
   EventDates();
```